# Bypass SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL in PHPUnit.xml

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there any way to run PHPUnit test case without SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL. I need to perform PHPUnit in an environment where only PHP cli is availabe. So can't put any url on SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL in phpunit.xml. So is there is any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit configuration provides sensible defaults that makes it possible to run test suites right off the bat without including a configuration file for a project.

Possible configuration options exposed as configurable in the [configuration file are documented](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/configuration.html#). There is no mention of `SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL`.

`SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL` is specific to Drupal projects and required in functional tests that are subclasses of [`Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.1/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php) or use [`Drupal\Core\Test\FunctionalTestSetupTrait`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php#L568)

If you are not writing any tests that require testing certain functionality on an installed site, you can subclass [`PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php) for your unit tests.

Even so the PHP CLI comes with a builtin webserver so I reckon one should be able to set `SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL` to `localhost`.